# Tableview display data based on Array result?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have three dictionary inside an `Array` called `_searchArray`. In the tableview, I want to display this array. Sometime this array can contains one or two or three dictionary.

```
{
    "chat_contacts" = {},
    "other_contacts" = {},
    "messagesContacts" = {}
}
```

TableView:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return _searchArray.count;
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {    
       if(section == 0){
            return [[_searchArray objectForKey:@"chatContacts"] count];
        }

        if(section == 1) {
            return [[_searchArray objectForKey:@"otherContacts"] count];
        }

        if(section == 2) {
            return [[[_searchArray objectForKey:@"messagesContacts"] objectForKey:@"messages"]count];
        }
}
```

Suppose if the array doesn't contain other_contacts, messages_contacts has to return in section 1.

If the array doesn't contain chat_contacts and other_contacts, messages_contacts has to return in section 0.

How can I display the proper data?

Comment: You can check the count in `viewForheader` delegate method and if array is blank then just return view as `0` height view which will not display on `tableview` and same for the `cellForRow' you can do it.

Comment: I think you did't get my question. I want to display the data based result. If array can 3 dict, It will display in order vice. but any thing is missing how can add the next dict in the place of missing dict ?.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is that return the proper count of sections in

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;`